# HttpRequest Post Method for submit and save data to a web site

Tags: c#, http

I am trying to log in a username password required web site and submit some data to there with httprequest post method. You can think this web site like a blog site which requires login first. And what i want to do is login this web site first then go to publish section, write something to the text box in this web site and click submit button to publish what i wrote.

By now i can login this web site by using http get method and take required viewstate,eventValidation values and cookies from that get method response and use them in my post method's postData with my username and password too then i can login. Then i can go to publish section too with cookies that i can get from previous get method too. But when i try to write something in this section and click publish(i am using telerik fiddler to track site traffic) it seems my post method there requires two values: "RadStyleSheetManager1_TSSM" and "radScriptMananer_TSM".Here is the post data taken from telerik fiddler:

```
RadStyleSheetManager1_TSSM=%3BTelerik.Web.UI%2C+Version%3D2013.3.1114.40%2C+Culture%3Dneutral%2C+PublicKeyToken%3D121fae78165ba3d4%3Atr-TR%3A8d3dfe81-f887-4a80-ad14-8e882b52e5e6%3A45085116%3A92753c09%3BTelerik.Web.UI.Skins%2C+Version%3D2013.3.1114.40%2C+Culture%3Dneutral%2C+PublicKeyToken%3D121fae78165ba3d4%3Atr-TR%3Ab4b6f2ef-e084-406b-ab93-e85df8d3c504%3A929e740d%3Abf721433&radScriptMananer_TSM=%3B%3BSystem.Web.Extensions%2C+Version%3D4.0.0.0%2C+Culture%3Dneutral%2C+PublicKeyToken%3D31bf3856ad364e35%3Atr-TR%3Ab7585254-495e-4311-9545-1f910247aca5%3Aea597d4b%3Ab25378d2%3BTelerik.Web.UI%2C+Version%3D2013.3.1114.40%2C+Culture%3Dneutral%2C+PublicKeyToken%3D121fae78165ba3d4%3Atr-TR%3A8d3dfe81-f887-4a80-ad14-8e882b52e5e6%3A16e4e7cd%3Aed16cbdc%3Af7645509%3A88144a7a%3A24ee1bba%3A92fe8ea0%3Af46195d3%3Afa31b949%3A874f8ea2%3A19620875%3A490a9d4e%3Abd8f85e4&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=6wx4EYFyJl3ifqKMXnl73eUuSZ5GDUmQeS37%2B0pXuuxST2MQswOtz0TNAdQJAn1EJAVVOpBNwfMw%2Bv9T1h9QV7RP223s%2BKW2V4v7cw5DRjF8dCD6aPRy%2Fc05L%2FN4%2F6fk&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=F9DFCEF0&__SCROLLPOSITIONX=0&__SCROLLPOSITIONY=484.5&__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED=&__EVENTVALIDATION=EoL4Hl1K4OYVfImHw6G258yEia9jidq0Of7D7aKvXV%2BtS%2FfPHY4oLQCLqczmD%2BfNotKYIJEYlbiZKLdoVSZs%2B7289pLFwVx43dXp2rQE5YFx9GEj0zXsDQUVL%2Bl1D%2F9qjX%2F7crYSCD1GO8zOyu6Yc4cIA4LYn2z88CBb0PEsRnLg90mipkZWXlkSMAMBYPC0D1vkop5GTJedn6exYcn52Q%2F%2Fj7%2BI8uVeW3LutytHQJVVqTev0n3gdVV6lc9arNMRpgeKdC8gmRZG8tmgiXqHVL9EHUnwAitWXgXMughl4D3xm%2FWbvZFH1LBtGe2djmpwZIF9NptxOpTRzKCJ18wywKRPdlMiM9Et6XLW5b90nY59qD8rAYJte2lzJ431lc9%2FkG%2Fkt5on%2B9%2FUl406dkabpV8HlPQK3tzfY4jOCxkoRgG7YRursHknTzhCTSXrFRRu3Fm3z0fK54c%2BVSukL68gP7L5tewoAXI4BPhSBpAKxglEBCkYe2vHrKZegarmuiMvL1bd08I5uVbX7o0XHm9lg0b2N2ZmltxxIFWvDzGa5BOIb0eq3Eoa%2FitJY%2BPI%2BfKyjerfU4607yeeGBW3MKk9g1y%2FMqeq0usnuvAj%2FjpDsgjdTLxVitTlxhmm4OleQUugb0AnuLLjquC34qx9YmzTfh3cbeT7G8b8niWM4%2FqOlQn1yYa%2FThr4QTHjORGlX81n6eStkkV5VejLfnuW6DDcN3tmMHPCXdUKy3XkwUvRiDeABv1SnvabWTytF3qmQH9xBfi3neofT%2FfmpFR5WPyXnoBFmGHXWHYAiySvs%2FklNc5NKakr8ncya9CYuuBWbegQolJNonKEtuKwVpPBRtTuufmh9f05IA3NEjYCe2BYvUZOOEZ8z7II1Vj6QpnyrKFzBIWLa4WhxoT7A2loA%2FUpBJoxajq7s8T2SYlO4SUU11ApkmtZNYIqppxaAj9HIyRldWQEpO859UXaXFLZ8jfaQLeD5DR8xSnQcYC5u4SzQBh3lHJP0dL6D4uhdLszF%2Ffs91vsRYwLscAL1W%2FF4B4E0pnQH3eoffoUuBKmfmLohB7TdgZB2j34NDApXamsa5XJtC6ulMPorsOcJc%2Flkguy2Q%3D%3D&ctl00%24PageId=&ctl00%24hIlk=1&ctl00%24lblSayfaSozlesme=&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24txtDosyaNoAra=3075924&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ucYSTDosyaBilgileri%24ucFaizHesaplamaTarih%24txtTarih=05.05.2020&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24btnYeniNotEkle=Yeni+Not+Ekle&ctl00_MessageWindowManager_ClientState=&ctl00_RadWindowMesajGoster_ClientState=&ctl00_wPrint_ClientState=&ctl00_PrintWindow_ClientState=&ctl00_RadWindowPopup_ClientState=
```

As you can see post data is too long but i think reason of failure is that i can't catch that "RadStyleSheetManager1_TSSM" and "radScriptMananer_TSM" values. Is that two values are neccessary to submit some data with post method or i am doing some other thing wrong ?

Below is my main code and http post method used in main code. Thx for your helps.

P.S: I am new to this site so please warn me if I cannot inform enough about my problem. I really want to achieve this post thing.

MAIN CODE

```
        string postData2 = "RadStyleSheetManager1_TSSM=%3BTelerik.Web.UI%2C+Version%3D2013.3.1114.40%2C+Culture%3Dneutral%2C+PublicKeyToken%3D121fae78165ba3d4%3Atr-TR%3A8d3dfe81-f887-4a80-ad14-8e882b52e5e6%3A45085116%3A92753c09%3BTelerik.Web.UI.Skins%2C+Version%3D2013.3.1114.40%2C+Culture%3Dneutral%2C+PublicKeyToken%3D121fae78165ba3d4%3Atr-TR%3Ab4b6f2ef-e084-406b-ab93-e85df8d3c504%3A929e740d%3Abf721433&radScriptMananer_TSM=%3B%3BSystem.Web.Extensions%2C+Version%3D4.0.0.0%2C+Culture%3Dneutral%2C+PublicKeyToken%3D31bf3856ad364e35%3Atr-TR%3Ab7585254-495e-4311-9545-1f910247aca5%3Aea597d4b%3Ab25378d2%3BTelerik.Web.UI%2C+Version%3D2013.3.1114.40%2C+Culture%3Dneutral%2C+PublicKeyToken%3D121fae78165ba3d4%3Atr-TR%3A8d3dfe81-f887-4a80-ad14-8e882b52e5e6%3A16e4e7cd%3Aed16cbdc%3Af7645509%3A88144a7a%3A24ee1bba%3A92fe8ea0%3Af46195d3%3Afa31b949%3A874f8ea2%3A19620875%3A490a9d4e%3Abd8f85e4&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE=" + viewState2 + "&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR="+ viewStateGenerator2 +"&__SCROLLPOSITIONX=0&__SCROLLPOSITIONY=682.5&__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED=&__EVENTVALIDATION=" + eventValidation2 + "&ctl00%24PageId=&ctl00%24hIlk=1&ctl00%24lblSayfaSozlesme=&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24txtDosyaNoAra=2022851&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ucYSTDosyaBilgileri%24ucFaizHesaplamaTarih%24txtTarih=05.05.2020&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ddlMalBilgiTuru=1&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ddlDigerBorclu=0&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24txtPlakaNo=deneme&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24txtMarka=deneme&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24txtModel=deneme&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24txtModelYili=2010&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ddlAracTuru=2&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24txtAracAciklama=deneme&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24btnMalVarlikKaydet=Kaydet&ctl00_MessageWindowManager_ClientState=&ctl00_RadWindowMesajGoster_ClientState=&ctl00_wPrint_ClientState=&ctl00_PrintWindow_ClientState=&ctl00_RadWindowPopup_ClientState=";
        string source5 = HttpMethods.Post("https://avukat.ckbogazici.com.tr/YTS/DosyaBilgileri.aspx?DosyaUN=" + ytsNo, "https://avukat.ckbogazici.com.tr/YTS/DosyaBilgileri.aspx?DosyaUN=" + ytsNo, postData2, cookies, "application / x - www - form - urlencoded", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9");
        if (source5.Contains("btnNotKaydet"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Submitted succesfully");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Problem!");
        }
```

POST METHOD

```
       public static string Post(string url, string referer, string postData, CookieContainer cookies, string contentType, string accept)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.CookieContainer = cookies;
        req.Referer = referer;
        req.UserAgent = "";
        req.ContentType = contentType;
        req.Accept = accept;
        req.ContentLength = postData.Length;

        Stream postStream = req.GetRequestStream();
        byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        postStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
        postStream.Dispose();

        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        cookies.Add(resp.Cookies);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        string src = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Dispose();          

        return (src);
```

And this is the web site's publish section's source code. As you can see "RadStyleSheetManager1_TSSM" and "radScriptMananer_TSM"'s values are blank so i cannot catch it.

```html
<body>
    <form method="post" action="./DosyaAra.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="RadStyleSheetManager1_TSSM" id="RadStyleSheetManager1_TSSM" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="radScriptMananer_TSM" id="radScriptMananer_TSM" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPZwUPOGQ3ZjEzZmZhMzdlMDc3TreYxBcpGwvEYQ+SuTTGuzY9U0wkCd6pJwHYOtNe5Ck=" />
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe the failure is on wrong MIME type: `"application / x - www - form - urlencoded"` looks like redundant spaces are there. Make it `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

Comment: Note that [`HttpWebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=netframework-4.8) class is obsolete, use [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8) instead.

Comment: Oh thank you very much i didn't see that redundant spaces. You saved me bro thanx a lot.